# Making an animation of the progressive plotting of imported data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, import, animation

I have managed to import data from an Excel XLSX file using Import.

```
dat = Import[
   "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Conductance\\mathfile.xlsx", {"Data"}];
```

There are two columns of data from which I would like to produce a ListAnimate / Animate plot.

I tried something like this:

```
points = Table[ListPlot[dat[[1, b]], PlotRange -> All], {b, 1, 10}];
ListAnimate[points]
```

This produces an animation but no points are plotted. The first point appears correctly, the rest seem to plot only a point corresponding to the first col.

The original data is in the form of a normal number (col 1) and a number using scientific notation, e.g., 4e-5 (col 2). Do I have to format my data in a different format?

Comment: Mathematica does not recognize numbers formatted like 4e-5. However, I think the import expression converts such numbers to Mathematica reals. Can't be sure because I don't have access to Excel or any .xlsx files.

Comment: @m_goldberg You can use ``Internal`StringToDouble``, that recognizes that notation, and the importer uses that.

Answer (score 4):

For speed reasons, I would avoid [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot) and just use [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) directly. Here is some sample data:

```
data = Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,0,10,.01}];
```

And, here is an animation:

```
Animate[
    Graphics[
        {Line[data[[;;i]]]},
        PlotRange->{{0,10},{-1,1}}
    ],
    {i, 1, Length[data], 1}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
dat = Import["C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Conductance\\mathfile.xlsx"{"Data"}];
points = Table[dat[[1, j]], {j, 1, 10}];

tag = Table[ Take[points, n], {n, 1, 8, 1}];
Manipulate [ListPlot[tag[[c]]], {c, 1, 8, 1}]
```

Comment: `points = data[[All, 2]]` is really much better way to extract column 2.